# Android stud. not building apk

Tags: android-studio, apk

my problem is that I want to make a signed apk file, I choose create signed apk file enter anything I need to enter, but the apk isn't appearing at the desktop (apk dest. location:Desktop)
Here is the build log:

```
Executing pre-compile tasks...
Running 'before' tasks
Checking sources
Running 'after' tasks
Finished, saving caches...
Executing post-compile tasks...
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to look like android studio Gradle  build log ...

Comment: Where to get it?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate signed apk in menu `build` -> `Generate signed bundle/apk`. You may need to create keystore.jks and save it because when you upload on playstore, you can only use the same keystore file